# AWS Lambda create EC2 and associate EIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to deploy an EC2 instance and associate an EIP to it, but I am getting and error when trying to associate the EIP because the instance is not running. This is my code:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
 
AMI = 'ami-0bf84....'    
INSTANCE_TYPE = 't2.micro'
KEY_NAME = 'EC2company'
SUBNET_ID = 'subnet-065....'
 
 
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
    instance = ec2.run_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        KeyName=KEY_NAME,
        SubnetId=SUBNET_ID,
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1
    )
        
    waiter = ec2.get_waiter('instance_running')
    
    try:
        response = ec2.associate_address(
            AllocationId='eipalloc-0bc.....',
            InstanceId=instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId'],
        )
        print(response)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
```

I suppose that the issue is related to be applying the waiter in the wrong way, and not sure how i should do it.

Comment: You need to call `waiter.wait()`. See: [EC2 waiters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [EC2 waiters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning), you can create a waiter with:

```
waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_running')
```

You then activate the waiter with:

```
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=['i-xxx']
```

It polls `EC2.Client.describe_instances()` every 15 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 40 failed checks.